# How to deploy a flask app to Bottle?

Tags: python, flask

I have write a flask project and I want to deploy it to `Bottle`.

I have tried to directly assign the Flask app to the app parameter, but it failed.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Flask` and `Bottle` are two micro-frameworks for Python.

You cannot deploy a flask application with bottle because bottle is a framework. Not a server, nor a a tool to deploy flask apps.

If you want to deploy your flask application on a server you already have, you will need to install a WSGI HTTP server to run your flask application. 
Take a look at:

- [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/)
- [uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

I you want your flask application hosted for you and you don't want to manage the server yourself, take a look at:

- [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python-o)
- [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/)